# Multiple columns into rows

Tags: sql, dataframe, amazon-redshift, data-manipulation, dbeaver

What query do I need to change the result

**FROM**

| key value | Attribute1 | Value1 | Attribute2 | Value2 | Attribute3 | Value3 | Attribute4 | Value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | abc | 54321 | def | Yes | ghi | No | jkl | 67890 |

**TO **

| key value | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | attribute1 | value1 |
| 12345 | attribute2 | value2 |
| 12345 | attribute3 | value3 |
| 12345 | attribute4 | value4 |

This is the query I have for the first table

```
select key value, attribute1, value 1, attribute2, value2, attribute3, value3, attribute4, value4, attribute5, value5
from tableA
```

I used UNION ALL but it slows down the process significantly so I don't want to use UNION ALL.

Comment: Why are you not using the `UNPIVOT` operator?

Comment: Can you share how I can use UNPIVOT in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Other Way(ORACLE):

```
select a.key_value
    , (
        case
            when b.rno = 1 then a.Attribute1
            when b.rno = 2 then a.Attribute2
            when b.rno = 3 then a.Attribute3
            when b.rno = 4 then a.Attribute4
        end
    ) as Attribute
    , (
        case
            when b.rno = 1 then a.Value1
            when b.rno = 2 then a.Value2
            when b.rno = 3 then a.Value3
            when b.rno = 4 then a.Value4
        end
    ) as Value
from (
    select '12345' as key_value, 'abc' as Attribute1,   '54321' as Value1, 'def' as Attribute2, 'Yes' as Value2, 'ghi' as Attribute3, 'No' as Value3, 'jkl' as Attribute4, '67890' as Value4 from dual
) a
cross join (
    select 1 as rno from dual
    union all
    select 2 as rno from dual
    union all
    select 3 as rno from dual
    union all
    select 4 as rno from dual
) b
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `unnest`. Here is the sample code:

```
-- Create the initial table
CREATE TABLE tableA (
    key INT,
    attribute1 TEXT,
    value1 TEXT,
    attribute2 TEXT,
    value2 TEXT,
    attribute3 TEXT,
    value3 TEXT,
    attribute4 TEXT,
    value4 TEXT
);

-- Insert sample data into the table
INSERT INTO tableA (key, attribute1, value1, attribute2, value2, attribute3, value3, attribute4, value4)
VALUES
    (12345, 'abc', '54321', 'def', 'Yes', 'ghi', 'No', 'jkl', '67890'),
    (54321, 'xyz', '98765', 'pqr', 'No', 'lmn', 'Yes', 'stu', '12345');

 
SELECT key , 
       unnest(array['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', 'attribute4']) AS attribute,
       unnest(array[attribute1, attribute2, attribute3, attribute4]) AS value
FROM tableA;
```

Here is the [sample fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/3lGsbnqM)

NB: I am using postgreSQL script based on your tag